# Toggling a Jquery typewriter effect

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am learning jQuery and as an experiment I have tried to combine a hide/show toggle effect with the typewriter effect of Jason Frame (http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html).

There are links on a page and when one is clicked a hidden  is shown and the type effect is triggered.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="inline-block"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;
}

(function($) {    

    $.fn.typewriter = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0;
            $ele.text('');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '| ' : ''));
                if (progress >= str.length) clearInterval(timer);
            }, 100);
        });
        return this;
    }; 

})(jQuery);
```

dAnd the HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="toggleMe('typewriter1'); $('#typewriter1').typewriter();">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a><span id="typewriter1" style='display:none'>, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>.
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMe('typewriter2'); $('#typewriter2').typewriter();">Pellentesque ut facilisis nulla.</a>
<span id="typewriter2" style='display:none'>Mauris ultricies  <a href="#" onclick="toggleMe('typewriter3'); $('#typewriter3').typewriter();">suscipit</a> <span id="typewriter3" style='display:none'>dolor</span> in ultrices.</span></p>
```

Obviously a few things go wrong and I can't really understand why. Notably:
1) The nested link (typewriter3) is not displayed. It seems that the HTML is stripped within a hidden typewriter span.
2) The last character of a span string is often left out.

Any suggestions to improve this code?

Thanks!

Comment: That plugin is not designed to work with *nested* spans as it works by replacing the text content only. Any child DOM elements are ignored. You would need to completely rewrite it to allow for recursive regeneration of all visible descendants.

Comment: Complete rewrite, with full recursion, below. I have some ideas to take this concept even further, so thanks for that. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice: Don't mix jQuery and inline `onclick` handlers. Much neater to use jQuery for all event handling. You can see how I combined all the handlers into one and use the `href`s to determine the targets.

I then proceeded to write a new version of typewriter from scratch. It uses a `contents()` iteration and `nodeType` checking to only modify the actual text parts of an element. The whole thing is recursive so it will work on any number of nested elements. It also fixes some end-state bugs you had in your code (which sometimes left the last character as `|`).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vLtL8uqa/1/

```
jQuery.fn.typewriter = function () {
    var recurse = function (node, delay) {
        // Only convert text nodes
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var str = node.textContent || '';
            node.textContent = '';
            var progress = 0;
            // Initial timer to delay next descendant
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Repeat timer until complete
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                    var ss = str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : '');
                    node.textContent = ss;
                    if (progress >= str.length) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        node.textContent = str;
                    }
                }, 100);
            }, delay * 100);
            delay += str.length;
        } else {
            var $node = $(node);
            if ($node.is(':visible')) {
                $(node).contents().each(function (index) {
                    delay = recurse(this, delay);
                });
            }
        }
        return delay;
    }
    this.each(function () {
        // Start with the specified node with delay = 0
        recurse(this, 0);
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.typewriter').click(function (e) {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $target.toggle().typewriter();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The start timing is progressively delayed to make it appear as if the operations happen sequentially (when in fact they all start in parallel on the same frame).

*Credit to [Jason Frame](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html) for the idea and the couple of lines of code I retained to-date* :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort. So interesting to see what you have done with the original plugin. I's be very interested to see to what project my question inspired you!! Thanks again...

Comment: Note: there is a serious *browser compatibility* issue with *this* version.